# Get last key of an object and insert in first position of keys

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have this object structure in Javascript:

```
{
  2015-08:367,
  2015-09:381,
  2015-10:390,
  2015-11:400,
  2015-12:396,
  PAYOR:"PCP",
}
```

And need get this result:

```
{
  PAYOR:"PCP",
  2015-08:367,
  2015-09:381,
  2015-10:390,
  2015-11:400,
  2015-12:396,
}
```

Comment: That's not valid syntax.

Comment: Why does object order matter? You usually pick values out by keys,

Comment: That's not a valid object, also the ordering of keys inside object can't be reliably sorted.

Comment: ["properties order in objects is not guaranteed in JavaScript"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5525795/2033671)

Answer (score 0):

Not a valid object, if you work with a valid array you have this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Answer (score 0):

Order of keys in JS objects is not guaranteed to be stable and can be implementation dependent.
As pmkro said, don't use it